# Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `v2_financieel`.`facturen_azie` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using workbench and I am trying to create a database with a table:

I just put this create database in the sql editor and execute it.

Of course I googled first for the error. But I cant find anything for this specific case.

```
-- Dumping database structure for v2_financieel
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `v2_financieel` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `v2_financieel`;

-- Dumping structure for table v2_financieel.facturen_azie
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `facturen_azie` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kantoor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `factuurnummer` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `factuurdatum` date NOT NULL,
  `merknaam_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `klant_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `omschrijving` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `aantal_afslagen` decimal(10,1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bonnummers` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `valuta` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EUR',
  `koers` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `koersdatum` date NOT NULL,
  `bedrag_euro` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `bedrag_valuta` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `btw` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `factuurbedrag` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `betaald` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `extra_bedrag` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `extra_omschrijving` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `creditfactuur` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `credit_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `betalingsdatum` date NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `facturen_azie_factuurnummer_unique` (`factuurnummer`),
  KEY `facturen_azie_merknaam_id_foreign` (`merknaam_id`),
  KEY `facturen_azie_klant_id_foreign` (`klant_id`),
  KEY `facturen_azie_kantoor_id_foreign` (`kantoor_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `search_azie` (`factuurnummer`,`omschrijving`),
  CONSTRAINT `facturen_azie_kantoor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`kantoor_id`) REFERENCES `kantoren` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `facturen_azie_klant_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`klant_id`) REFERENCES `klanten` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=496 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

But I get this errror:

```
12:02:40    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `facturen_azie` (   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `kantoor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   `factuurnummer` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,   `factuurdatum` date NOT NULL,   `merknaam_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   `klant_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,   `omschrijving` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,   `aantal_afslagen` decimal(10,1) unsigned NOT NULL,   `bonnummers` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `valuta` char(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'EUR',   `koers` decimal(8,4) unsigned NOT NULL,   `koersdatum` date NOT NULL,   `bedrag_euro` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,   `bedrag_valuta` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,   `btw` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,   `factuurbedrag` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,   `betaald` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `extra_bedrag` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,   `extra_omschrijving` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,   `creditfactuur` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `credit_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `betalingsdatum` date NOT NULL,   `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,   `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),   UNIQUE KEY `facturen_azie_factuurnummer_unique` (`factuurnummer`),   KEY `facturen_azie_merknaam_id_foreign` (`merknaam_id`),   KEY `facturen_azie_klant_id_foreign` (`klant_id`),   KEY `facturen_azie_kantoor_id_foreign` (`kantoor_id`),   FULLTEXT KEY `search_azie` (`factuurnummer`,`omschrijving`),   CONSTRAINT `facturen_azie_kantoor_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`kantoor_id`) REFERENCES `kantoren` (`id`),   CONSTRAINT `facturen_azie_klant_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`klant_id`) REFERENCES `klanten` (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=496 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci    Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `v2_financieel`.`facturen_azie` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")    0.359 sec
```

Comment: Does the tables `kantoren` and `klanten` exists? Does each contains the field `id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL` which is primary key or unique indexed? Does

Comment: The rules for creating foreign keys can be found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html